# Transposing all but the first column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, transpose, melt

I have got the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'Jan': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Feb': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Mar': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
```

Which produces

```
   ISIN Jan   Feb    Mar
0  A    40000 50000  42000
1  B    40000 50000  42000
2  C    40000 50000  42000
```

I am trying to produce an output where the data looks like this:

```
   Date     A    B      C
0  Jan    40000 40000  40000
1  Feb    50000 50000  50000
2  Mar    42000 42000  42000
```

My first pass as this was to simply transpose the analysis using

```
df = df.T
```

That sort of worked except for the ISIN row (ie what I want as my column headers) were still sitting in the dataset:

```
           0     1      2
  ISIN     A     B      C
  Jan    40000 40000  40000
  Feb    50000 50000  50000
  Mar    42000 42000  42000
```

I then tried to pop out the ISIN row before doing the transpostion, ie

ISIN = df.pop('ISIN')
df = df.T

That stripped out the ISIN row but then when I try to insert my popped column (using df.insert) and change the axis...I get stuck

I also tried using df.melt but I struggled to get the right things in the right places

I'm sure that this is very easy but I'm going around in circles here and I would really appreciate some wisdom.

Thanks!

Comment: In your initial DataFrame, `ISIN` is a column. Try setting it as the index, then transposing: `df = df.set_index('ISIN').T`

Comment: Thank you. I am clearly a dunce - but fortunately you are not!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When transposing, the index becomes columns and the columns index, so you need to first set ISIN as the index and then transpose.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'Jan': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Feb': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'Mar': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
df.set_index('ISIN', inplace=True)
print(df.T)
```

Which produces:

```
ISIN      A      B      C
Jan   40000  50000  42000
Feb   40000  50000  42000
Mar   40000  50000  42000
```

Answer (score 1):

When you transpose a DataFrame, you also exchange the index and the columns. So you must explicitelyset the index:

```
df = df.set_index('ISIN').T.reset_index()
```

You would get:

```
ISIN index      A      B      C
0      Jan  40000  50000  42000
1      Feb  40000  50000  42000
2      Mar  40000  50000  42000
```

The values are correct but the labels are off. You can fix them with `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.set_index('ISIN').T.rename_axis('Date').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

You get as expected:

```
  Date      A      B      C
0  Jan  40000  50000  42000
1  Feb  40000  50000  42000
2  Mar  40000  50000  42000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.rename(columns={'ISIN': 'Date'}).set_index('Date').T
```

Result:

```
Date      A      B      C
Jan   40000  50000  42000
Feb   40000  50000  42000
Mar   40000  50000  42000
```